# Is command line rendering faster than normal rendering?

Tags: rendering, command-line

blender users!

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html

This manual write-on command line rendering is faster than regular rendering.
I tried it, but the result was that the speed did not change that much.

Is it true the command line rendering is faster?

Comment: faster doesn't mean "half the time" - it just means "faster" which can be from 0.00001 milliseconds to hours....so since you already recognized yourself that the speed changed, i do not really understand the question!? If you want to know how you can render faster - just search for that here or on google and you will find a lot of answers like decreasing samples etc.

Comment: True. The difference can also be drastically impacted depending on your test render, your hardware. Also whether you render a single frame or a sequence. But in the absolute: there's no UI to display and update, so your hardware can focus "more" on rendering.